# Conversion from int16_t to uint32_t

Tags: c++, c

```
int16_t s;
uint32_t ui = s;
```

Is the result of converting a `int16_t` value to a `uint32_t` value compiler dependent? If not, what's the rule?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The results are well-defined; non-negative values stay the same, and negative values are reduced modulo 2^32. But the situations where **exact** sized types like `int16_t` and `uint32_t` are needed are quite rare. There's really no need for anything other than `int` and `unsigned long` here: those types have **at least** as many bits as `int16_t` and `uint32_t` and, unlike `int16_t` and `uint32_t`, they're **required to exist** on any conforming implementation. If you really really want the sexy new sized types, at least go for portability with `int_least16_t` and `uint_least32_t`.

Comment: Where is it specified in the standard?

Comment: @updogliu: C++11 4.7/2: "If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
integer (modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type)." Also, C99 6.3.1.3, since you seem to be asking about two different languages.